# SHA1 hash of Java doesn't match with that of Perl

Tags: java, perl, sha1

How can I get Java's MessageDigest.digest() result to match with Perl's sha1->digest ??
MessageDigest.digest() takes string.getBytes() where in Perl I'm just passing a string to the sha1 object. Is that why it is failing?

JAVA:

```
String mystring ="zWh9YZX3";
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(mysrting.getBytes())
```

Perl:

```
$mystring ="zWh9YZX3";  
$sha1 = Digest::SHA1->new;
$sha1->add($mystring);
$digest = $sha1->digest;
```

Comment: Without code, how can we tell what you did wrong?  But SHA1 is a standard function, and given the same data any implementation must produce identical results.  Therefore, you're not passing the same data.

Comment: @cjm: Or not calling the same function :)

Comment: You didn't specify which module you're using, but it's practically guaranteed that the string you pass to the sha1 has to be bytes. Did you perhaps encode the string before hashing it in Java but not in Perl?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it's not sufficient. Could you precicely specify what `mystring` and `$mystring` contain? (`use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($mystring));`

Comment: ok, since you just have ASCII chars, it's not an encoding problem, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same on Perl and Java.

```
$ perl x.pl | od -t x1
0000000 f7 d4 ae 4d bd df 5a d3 61 65 bb f8 be 60 45 03
0000020 e4 82 9d b6
0000024

$ javac x.java && java x | od -t x1
0000000 f7 d4 ae 4d bd df 5a d3 61 65 bb f8 be 60 45 03
0000020 e4 82 9d b6
0000024
```

`x.pl`:

```
use Digest::SHA1;
my $bytes ="zWh9YZX3";  
my $sha1 = Digest::SHA1->new;
$sha1->add($bytes);
print $sha1->digest;
```

`x.java`:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        String mystring ="zWh9YZX3";
        byte[] bytes = mystring.getBytes();
        byte[] hash = sha1.digest(bytes);
        System.out.write(hash, 0, hash.length);
    }
}
```

Note that you're not hashing the same thing. In the Perl code, you're hashing the bytes `zWh9YZX3`. In the Java code, you're hashing environment specific encoding of the characters `zWh9YZX3`. If you happened to have bytes larger than 127, the result would be different.

The Perl equivalent of the Java above would be:

```
use Digest::SHA1;
use Encode;
my $mystring ="zWh9YZX3";  
my $bytes = encode('???', $mystring);
my $sha1 = Digest::SHA1->new;
$sha1->add($bytes);
print $sha1->digest;
```

Don't forget to use `use utf8;` if your source code is encoded using UTF-8. (Otherwise, it's effectively expected to be iso-8859-1.)

---

On working with the digest in hex form:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::SHA1 qw( sha1_hex );

my $bytes = "zWh9YZX3";
my $digest_hex = sha1_hex($bytes);

print("INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (UNHEX('$digest_hex'))\n");
```

Comment: which platform is this on? Mine's Ubuntu for both Perl and Java.

Comment: Debian. What differences do you see?

Comment: I guess he just prints digests differently. I see coincidences in digests which can't be if input was different.

Comment: You're right, the hashes are the same. I guess it's all going wrong because I'm not directly inserting $sha1->digest into my MYSQL db. I'm writing sha1->digest to a .sql file and then running it against my db. I have to do this because the perl script and db are on 2 different machines and I can't run the perl script on the db machine.

Comment: @Sapphire, You might have better luck if you work with the hex form of it, and have the SQL "dehex" it.

Comment: @ikegami can you give me an example of that please? I'm not sure how to get SQL to "dehex" the data.

Comment: MySQL has `UNHEX`. See the addition to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of the strings, in Java string.getBytes() will use the default platform encoding which may be different to the encoding used by the perl function. You must ensure that you use the same encoding for both platforms.

Comment: I'm using Perl not PHP. How can I check the encoding? I can't touch the Java code, I only have Perl to play with.

Comment: typo, now corrected :D But the point is still valid - you must use the same encoding for both languages

Answer (score 0):

Compare the hashes visually. Probably they differ in framing, which is easily visible and fixable. If the codes are completely different, then check the "salt" and/or binary format of input data.

Comment: They do look different visually.

Comment: You mean absolutely different with no matching sequences?

Comment: Does Perl use Unicode? Java uses Unicode, so `getBytes()` returns unicode bytes of the string.

Comment: Can you print both digests in HEX format please? Do you see you have "M", "Z" and "ae" sequences in same positions in both digests?

Comment: Unicode code points don't fit in bytes. And what `getBytes` returns has nothing to do with Unicode. "Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array." That could very well be UTF-8 bytes (but not Unicode bytes).

Comment: This is just a flame. Bytes are part of UTF-8, and UTF-8 is part of Unicode standard (see section 3.9). So UTF-8 bytes are of Unicode. Think simple!